# What does "dignity of exile" mean?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

After hunter seeker failed to kill Paul in *Dune* (2021), Mohiam speaks to Vladimir in a vacuum-covered space:

> Vladimir: There's no satellites over Arrakis. The Atreides will die in
> the dark.
>
> Mohiam: On that matter, Duke Leto Atreides means nothing to our order.
> But his wife is under our protection and by extension, her son. Allow
> them the **dignity of exile**.

What does "dignity of exile" mean?

Comment: https://youtu.be/4vPRdOLdW1g?t=43

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dignity of exile as opposed to the ignominy of capture or death.

By the rules of kanly (vendetta), Vladimir Harkonnen's beef is with the elder Atreides rather than his son or his concubine Jessica and he's not supposed to kill any of them, just dispossess them of their planet and put them into [exile](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Tupile).

> Rabban swallowed. “You must take immediate measures to hold a hostage
> from each House Minor,” the Baron said. “As far as anyone off Arrakis
> must learn, this was straightforward House-to-House battle. The
> Sardaukar had no part in it, you understand? **The Duke was offered the
> usual quarter and exile,** but he died in an unfortunate accident before
> he could accept. He was about to accept, though. That is the story.
> And any rumor that there were Sardaukar here, it must be laughed at.”
>
> <sub><sup>Dune by Frank Herbert</sup></sub>

Mohiam is very well aware that bad Vlad will try to kill every single Atreides in order to end the blood feud. She's asking him to observe the rules and let Paul and Jessica go into exile rather than murdering them.